# a Failed IOC Injection - Spring and JSF integration

Tags: spring, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to integrate jsf with spring and 
inject service classes on my managed bean

My managed bean:

```
package web;

import java.util.List;   
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import mapping.*;
import gestion.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@SessionScoped
public class AjoutChamp {
    private  Module module;
    private int m;
    private int etape;
    private int menu;
    private int TypeChamp;
    private int action;
    private int selecteur;
    private String valeur_selecteur;
    private String contexte;
    private String texte;

    @Autowired
    private GestionEtape gEtape;
    @Autowired
    private GestionModule gModule;

    private List<Module> listeModule;

    @PostConstruct
    void init(){
        listeModule=gModule.selectAll();
    }

    public int getM() {
        return m;
    }
    public void setM(int m) {
        this.m = m;
    }
    public List<Module> getListeModule() {
        return listeModule;
    }
    public void setListeModule(List<Module> listeModule) {
        this.listeModule = listeModule;
    }

    public GestionEtape getgEtape() {
        return gEtape;
    }
    public void setgEtape(GestionEtape gEtape) {
        this.gEtape = gEtape;
    }
    public GestionModule getgModule() {
        return gModule;
    }
    public void setgModule(GestionModule gModule) {
        this.gModule = gModule;
    }

    public Module getModule() {
        return module;
    }
    public void setModule(Module module) {
        this.module = module;
    }
    public int getEtape() {
        return etape;
    }
    public void setEtape(int etape) {
        this.etape = etape;
    }
    public int getMenu() {
        return menu;
    }
    public void setMenu(int menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }
    public int getTypeChamp() {
        return TypeChamp;
    }
    public void setTypeChamp(int typeChamp) {
        TypeChamp = typeChamp;
    }
    public int getAction() {
        return action;
    }
    public void setAction(int action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
    public int getSelecteur() {
        return selecteur;
    }
    public void setSelecteur(int selecteur) {
        this.selecteur = selecteur;
    }
    public String getValeur_selecteur() {
        return valeur_selecteur;
    }
    public void setValeur_selecteur(String valeur_selecteur) {
        this.valeur_selecteur = valeur_selecteur;
    }
    public String getContexte() {
        return contexte;
    }
    public void setContexte(String contexte) {
        this.contexte = contexte;
    }
    public String getTexte() {
        return texte;
    }
    public void setTexte(String texte) {
        this.texte = texte;
    }


    public AjoutChamp(){}

}
```

my applicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="web"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="gestion"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yo?useSSL=false"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="factory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop
         key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
         </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
        <value>mapping</value>
        </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `applicationContext.xml`:

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

and

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

So, your `applicationContext.xml` should look like this.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
        ...
    </beans>
```

Add the spring-context library to your project too.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version><!-- version of Spring context. --></version>
</dependency>
```

If you're using Maven.

Comment: It say it can't find the BasicDataSource class.  You do not have this dependency on your project: <dependency>     <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>     <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>     <version>1.4</version> </dependency>

Comment: One thing, don't change the title of question.  It will make the answer irrelevant to the question.  If you like to see a sample project the you can use, visit this link https://github.com/rburawes/spring-hibernate-demo.  I've uploaded my test project that I've created ages ago.  I've just updated the dependencies.

Comment: You mean pom.xml right? :) BTW, replace it with 'org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource'.  I've updated it to use the dbcp.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this as the answer.  Could you please put the original title and details back?  That way, other guys with the same issue might find this question useful to them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong combination

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

Weird combination

```
@Component
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@SessionScoped
```

Both have all been discussed in Stackoverflow.

Comment: what about this ? http://www.journaldev.com/7112/jsf-spring-integration-example-tutorial